# How can I use INNER JOIN in this situation or better way to do it?

Tags: mysql, sql

I have this one problem that I've encountered, sorry if this is a newbie question but I haven't met this situation before so I don't even know what's call or how to search for a keyword to find the ways to solve it.

I have a `History_result` table, that has question_ID as a foreign key to the `question` table, answer_result is a foreign key to the `answers` table, history_ID is a foreign key to the `histories` table

`History_result table`

[image]

My query is to get all the columns in the `history_result` table and get question_description based on question_ID, anwser_description based on answer_result (which is answer_ID, too!)

Here's my query:

```
db.query("
SELECT history_result.*, questions.question_desc, answers.answer_desc  
FROM history_result
INNER JOIN questions ON (history_result.question_ID = questions.question_ID) 
INNER JOIN answers ON (history_result.answer_result = answers.answer_ID) 
WHERE history_ID =? 
ORDER BY history_ID ASC 
")
```

What I don't know is the last column, which is `history_ID`, it has foreign key from the `Histories` table, and it's contain 2 more foreign key columns, which I want to access in to get (user_ID to get username), (quiz_ID to get quiz_description)

Here's how it is:

[image]

If my explanation is too hard to understand, here's a relationship table that I have made

[image]

Can I still use INNER JOIN for this situation or do I have a better approaching method? Please provide me some, thanks!

Comment: Add additional joins with `histories`, `users`, and `quizs` to get `username` and `quizname`.

Comment: Sorry, I still don't get it, can you please explain it in more detail.

Comment: What don't you get? You join with them the same way you joined with the other tables.

Comment: Oh, so I can do that right away? I thought I have to INNER JOIN the users, then INNER JOIN the quizs, and from then I have to INNER JOIN deeper into user_ID and quiz_ID to get the name of each of it out...

Comment: Remember `inner join` may not display results which does not have a match, if `inner join` drops some results, use `left join` and then `select distinct hr* ....`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just add additional joins with those tables.

```
SELECT hr.*, q.question_desc, a.answer_desc, u.username, qz.quizname
FROM history_result AS hr
INNER JOIN questions AS q ON (hr.question_ID = q.question_ID) 
INNER JOIN answers ON (hr.answer_result = a.answer_ID) 
INNER JOIN histories AS h ON h.history_id = hr.history_id
INNER JOIN users AS u ON u.user_id = h.user_id
INNER JOIN quizs AS qz ON qz.quiz_id = h.quiz_id
WHERE hr.history_ID =? 
ORDER BY hr.history_ID ASC
```